# mysql 5.7 cursor not returning any values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

Mysql (version 5.7) cursor not working. I tried many times and checked online could not find what is wrong.

It is looping through correctly as many records in the currency table. But when I try to read from the cursor it is only returning null and not the actual values from the table currency. The currency table has data.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc2;

CREATE PROCEDURE proc2()
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE code VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT code FROM currency;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN myCursor;

    delete from dummy;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH myCursor INTO code;   

         IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE read_loop;
         END IF;

        insert into dummy(name) values(code);

    END LOOP read_loop;

    CLOSE myCursor;

End;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing this with a loop instead of just `INSERT INTO dummy (name) SELECT code from currency`?

Comment: Thanks, this is just pseudo code. Actually, I want to iterate all records in a temp table and for every record, I want to insert into 2 other tables. This is to bulk uploaded around 3 million records.

Comment: Then I can't see any reason why it's not working.

Comment: It might still be better to do two `INSERT ... SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

At last, it worked with below change to the script. (i.e. after adding table alias.)

For some reason, the column I tried out 'code' expects an alias. Maybe a reserved keyword, not sure.

```
 DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT c.code FROM currency c;
```